# Javascript problem or more lack of knowledge than anything

Tags: javascript

This is my current code below.  It is generating a random number for me on loading the page and works fine for the target **div**.  However, I want this to run this function within 8 separate divs.  I obviously cannot have 8 divs with the same id so I changed this to `getElementByClassName` and changed the class on my `div` to `vvv` and got rid of the **id** but for some reason this doesn't work?

Also, do I need anything else in my script to call this function for more than one div?  Any help much appreciated!

```
<script>
    let text = "VAC";       
        
    window.onload = function () {
        var output = document.getElementById("vvv");        
        setInterval(function () {
            output.innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * (115 - 105 + 1)) + 105 + " " + text; 
        }, 2000);//this value is the time between generating the number//
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Note that you don't need `window.onload`, put your script code in its own file (not in your HTML) and load it as `<script src="yourfile.js" async defer></script>` so that it loads without blocking the page (thanks to `async`), and only _runs_ once the document is ready (thanks to `defer`). Having said that, if your problem is with more than one div, so show that problem (with 2 divs, not 8, because you just need "more than one").

Comment: It might be useful to review [ask] and what constitutes a [mcve].  This question contains a snippet of code from what previously _was_ "working", a vague-ish description of what you have changed that is "not working", not enough code to actually run (no markup, for instance), no clear description of what it is you are trying to accomplish, and a statement of "it doesn't work" without any additional context given.  Remember, the community only has the information you provide, and it will be hard to assist you without a full understanding of your goals and problem.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for the response and I will take on board what you have suggested in terms of better explaining the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: Thank you for the async and defer suggestion.  Definitely going to put this into practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for getElementsByClassName (not getElementByClassName).

```js
let text = "VAC";

let outputs = document.getElementsByClassName("vvv");

let randomDivs = function() {
  for (let output in outputs) {
    outputs[output].innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * (115 - 105 + 1)) + 105 + " " + text
  }
}
randomDivs()
setInterval(randomDivs, 2000); //this value is the time between generating the number//
```

```html
<div class="vvv"></div>
<div class="vvv"></div>
<div class="vvv"></div>
<div class="vvv"></div>
<div class="vvv"></div>
<div class="vvv"></div>
<div class="vvv"></div>
<div class="vvv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may write it like this.

```
<body>
    <div class="vvv">1234</div>
    <div class="vvv">1234</div>
    <div class="vvv">1234</div>
    <script>
        let text = "VAC";       
        var output = document.getElementsByClassName("vvv"); //you can use getElementsByTagName("div") as well
        setInterval(function (){
            Array.from(output).forEach((item, index) => {item.innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * (115 - 105 + 1)) + 105 + " " + text;}
        )}, 2000)
    </script>
</body>
```

Note: Didn't realize it was answered already with similar approach. You may try getElementsByTagName("div") as well as suggested. But it has it's limitations too.